# Symfony setParameter does not work properly

Tags: symfony, query-builder

Ok, so I couldn't figure out as to why the query builder doesn't work when a variable is passed to the setParameter.

This works:

```
public function findByMatch($name)
    {
        $result = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->select('u.firstname, u.lastname')
            ->where('u.firstname LIKE :fname')
            ->setParameter('fname', ' % '.'paul'.' %')
            ;

        return $result->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

but when the criteria is passed via a variable, it doesn't, it returns $name as null

```
  // from an entity
    $matches = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findByMatch($type);

   //.........

   // repo
    public function findByMatch($name)
        {
            $result = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
                ->select('u.firstname, u.lastname')
                ->where('u.firstname LIKE :fname')
                ->setParameter('fname', ' % '.$name. ' %')
                ;

            return $result->getQuery()->getResult();
        }
```

Drilling it further down, this doesn't work as well, so it's not that the variable isn't passed.

```
public function findByMatch($name = "paul")
    {
        $result = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->select('u.firstname, u.lastname')
            ->where('u.firstname LIKE :fname')
            ->setParameter('fname', ' % '.$name. ' %')
            ;

        //return $result;

        return $result->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

Comment: Either $name is not set or the code you posted does not match your actual code.  And putting spaces around the % is a bit strange.  You really want to match " paul" instead of "paul" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, like Cerad said, I think it's your spaces around the % that are messing with your query.
I tested some combinations and it seems that only this one it working :

```
->setParameter('fname', '%' . $name . '%')
```

So if you don't need those spaces specifically, I suggest you remove them.